# Can't get permission to save and .xml file to disk with python

Tags: python, macos, file, permissions, save

I have this code:

```
def display(self):
    print self.doc.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
    strigName ='/Users/my_user/Desktop/python/' + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + '.xml'
    print strigName
    with open(strigName, "ws") as f:
        f.write(self.doc.toprettyxml(indent="  "))
```

that saves and xml file with a timestamp on the name to a path. The problem is that I can only save it to the same directory the script is. When I try to save it in the path shown above it gives me "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:" even running the python script with sudo, and yes my user is Admin. What's wrong?

Comment: do you have full control of that directory? this is probably a case of access rights/permissions or either you have the same file you are writing to which is already open or being used by another service!

Comment: check your path? which OS you are using, if you are using sudo I assume it is linux? usually there is no /Users folder

Comment: also which mode is "ws" I haven't seen it earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colons aren't allowed in OS X filenames. `str(datetime.datetime.now())` is `'2012-03-30 14:20:46'`

You could replace the colons with dashes in your string before using it, or use something like `time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", time.localtime())` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: Colons *are* allowed in Mac OS X filenames in the POSIX layer. `touch ~/colon:colon`  :-)

Comment: In Finder it shows up as `/`, of course, which is just as weird since Finder doesn't seem to like colon-separated filenames anymore.  :-)